# Scripting a precompiled Vim with Python, Perl... -- are the DLLs all I need?

Tags: windows, vim

Assume I download a precompiled Vim (all required settings are enabled) on Windows. Now, I want to script it using Python, Perl, and whatever else Vim supports. Are the DLLs all I'm going to need (for example `python27.dll` without `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe`)?

What about GNU/Linux? What is the alternative to `python27.dll` there?

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine, I have an executable called `python2` in one of my executable folders. I can run `python2 file.py` in the Terminal to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the DLLs and any corresponding language runtime files (e.g. modules).

What you usually do is:

1. Find out which language version your Vim binary has been compiled against (e.g. by observing the `Linking:` part of the `:version` output).
2. Download and install a corresponding package of the language.
3. (On Windows:) Ensure that the DLL is accessible to Vim (by augmenting the system PATH, copying the DLLs into the `system32` folder, ...; the installer may do that already for you).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but do I need to have the entire package of the language, or would the DLL suffice?

Comment: It's definitely safer to have the entire package. Try it out (as this depends on the language); if you get "module not found" errors, the DLL isn't enough.